# How to build expandable child rows for table (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at my jsfiddle works perfectly but as this is for a mobile website im really tight for space on the page so what I'd like to do is have some kind of child row for each row of data in my table which expands.

Here's my tables I currently have a filter and a page load sort going on anyone know how I can add child rows? Kind of like how [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) does it?

https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/7/

HTML

```
<h1>Table sorting on page load with paging</h1>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>

<h2>Second table below</h2>

<div class="sort_paging">

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter-free" /> Free Handset
    </p>

    <table class="internalActivities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£364.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.40 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.30 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.04 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£134.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.19 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£120.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.22 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£10.33 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£40.45 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="handsetcost">£200.00 upfront</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£30.84 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£16.14 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£12.10 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£14.02 per month</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td>data</td>
                <td><span class="free">No upfront cost</span>
                    <br><span class="amount">£50.88 per month</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="seeMoreRecords" value="More">
    <input type="button" class="seeLessRecords" value="Less">

</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    sortPaging: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var container = $(this);
            var dataRows = [];

            /**
             * Create an array of all rows with its value (this assumes that the amount is always a number.
             * You should add error checking!!
             * Also assumes that all rows are data rows, and that there are no header rows. Adjust selector appropriately.
             */
            container.find('.internalActivities > tbody > tr').each(function(i, j) {
                dataRows.push({
                    'amount': parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').text().replace(/£/, "")),
                    'row': $(this)
                });
            })

            //Sort the data smallest to largest
            dataRows.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.amount - b.amount;
            });

            //Remove existing table rows.  This assumes that everything should be deleted, adjust selector if needed :).
            container.find('.internalActivities > tbody').empty();

            //Add rows back to table in the correct order.
            dataRows.forEach(function(ele) {
                container.find('.internalActivities > tbody').append(ele.row);
            })


            var trs = container.find(".internalActivities tbody tr");
            var btnMore = container.find(".seeMoreRecords");
            var btnLess = container.find(".seeLessRecords");
            var trsLength = trs.length;
            var currentIndex = 3,
                page = 3;

            trs.hide();
            trs.slice(0, currentIndex).show();
            checkButton();

            btnMore.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                trs.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + page).show();
                currentIndex += page;
                checkButton();
            });

            btnLess.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                trs.slice(currentIndex - page, currentIndex).hide();
                currentIndex -= page;
                checkButton();
            });

            function checkButton() {
                var currentLength = trs.filter("tr:visible").length;

                if (currentLength >= trsLength) {
                    btnMore.hide();
                } else {
                    btnMore.show();
                }

                if (trsLength > page && currentLength > page) {
                    btnLess.show();
                } else {
                    btnLess.hide();
                }

            }
            container.find('.filter-free').change(function() {
                var $all = container.find(".internalActivities tbody tr").hide();
                trs = this.checked ? $all.has('.free') : $all;
                trsLength = trs.length;
                trs.slice(0, page).show();
                currentIndex = page;
            });
            container.find('.filter-free').click(function() {
                container.find('.seeLessRecords').hide();
            });
        })
    }
});

$('.sort_paging').sortPaging();
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
tbody{
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("thead").click(function(){ //or add your own (+) element as the trigger
    $(this).parent().find("tbody").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: this makes no sense I think you have misunderstood the question.. https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/15/ this is what im trying to do - add a child row to each row - and still have the functions function correctly